# Getting a speedbar to display a tree for org-mode headings

Tags: org-mode, speedbar

Is there a way I can get speedbar to give a complete top level tree and click through to lower levels?

treemacs does it (but doesn't have buffer, info, etc minor modes) ...

speedbar can produce a tree of headings for org-mode files although the default settings need a slight tweak:

```
;; default is (speedbar-prefix-group-tag-hierarchy speedbar-trim-words-tag-hierarchy)
(setq speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method '(speedbar-trim-words-tag-hierarchy))
```

For example, for this org-file:

```
* Places
** Queensland
*** Tamborine
foo bar
*** Gold Coast
**** Various
bar foo
**** Restaurants
foobar
*** Days out

...
```

The default settings give this:

```
~/Sync/
0:[-] bh.org *
1: {-} *  (Places)
2:  > * Places
2:  > * Recipes
2:  > * Health
2:  > * Lists
2:  > * Things
2:  > * Fotki
2:  > * Probus
2:  > * Ironies
1: {-} **
2:  {-} ** 
3:   {+} ** A
3:   {+} ** B
3:   {+} ** C to ** G
3:   {+} ** H to ** L
3:   {+} ** M
3:   {+} ** N to ** R
3:   {+} ** S to ** Wheelbarrow
```

... a rather mangled list, and the top level headings are truncated to the first 8, but at least a tree. With the tweak above, I get this:

```
~/Sync/
0:[-] bh.org *
1: > * Places
1: > ** Queensland
1: > *** Tamborine
1: > *** Gold Coast
1: > **** Various
1: > **** Restaurants
1: > *** Days out
```

... at least it's in the original order and not truncated - but it's totally flat - the tree structure has gone.

Comment: I don't know much about speedbar, but at least for the 8-char truncation, you can increase the width of the speedbar frame, can't you?

Comment: @NickD - sorry, I wasn't clear - it's truncating to the first 8 top rank items, not chars.